# Measuring the aggregate ... "we" vs "I"

Tags: survey, measurement-error, measurement, survey-sampling

I am involved with a project measuring organizational behavior.

My colleagues are split in terms of measures reading "we feel..." vs "I feel..." as the subject of the measurement.

Personally, I think we should focus on the "I" to avoid error associated with people mindreading, so to speak. We use multilevel modeling so this just seems to make most sense. (Others may aggregate to means and other descriptive without hlm, however).

What are opinions on this issue?

Best practices for measurement of a cluster... do we want individual perceptions or individual perceptions of what most people within the cluster think?

References appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Attitude research consistently distinguishes between one's own attitudes and one's perceptions of the attitudes of others. This distinction makes sense because people have immediate access to their own attitudes in a way they don't to the attitudes of others. In fact, the word "attitude" is often defined such that one can't be mistaken about one's own attitude. On the other hand, one could always have a mistaken impression of the attitudes of others. More broadly, the self–other distinction figures largely in psychology.

That's why psychological questionnaires rarely ask about "we" statements. If you're interested in the subject's self-perceptions, you ask about "I" statements. If you're interested in the subject's perceptions of others, you ask about things like "my coworkers" or "other kids my age". "We" statements muddy the issue.